# Angular ChangedAfterChecked error. What values are used for comparision

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

In angular dev mode a check is performed to check if there has been a bad update of properties.
This must have been done by checking the two values with each other. What are the values that are considered here for comparision?

Example:

```
<span>{{name}}</span>
```

So to check for the `name` which values does the angular compare. When or after which life cycle hooks are these values stored for comparision?

My understanding...
When a binding (a interpolation or a property binding etc) is updated, the updated value is stored some place. And when change detection cycle is completed, a check is done with current value of the binding to the value stored before. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helped me understand the issue.

https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error

Simply put, whenever a value is updated either due to interpolation or for property binding, it is saved as `Oldvalue`. This can happen at different points in the change detection cycle. This old value is compared with the value present while running noChange check later on.